# Unable to set proxy with BrowserMobProxy while modifying http header request in Selenium with Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, selenium3

I am able to modify http request header using BrowserMobProxy, the same way explained

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/37318/9043

But, the problem I am having at the moment is, that I am executing my scenarios on dev/local/playpen environment (environment before System integration testing). And to open the website on this environment needs proxy to set.

When I set my proxy then it fails to modify header and apply the proxy. When I comment the proxy part then it easily modifies the header.

```
BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
proxy.start(0);
Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);


proxy.addRequestFilter((request, contents, messageInfo)->{
    request.headers().add("some-header-attribute", "RandomeValue");
    System.out.println(request.headers().entries().toString());
    return null;
});

String _host = Utils.getConfigValue("proxy.host");
String _port = Utils.getConfigValue("proxy.port");

seleniumProxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy(_host + ":" + _port);
seleniumProxy.setSslProxy(_host + ":" + _port);
seleniumProxy.setFtpProxy(_host + ":" + _port);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

String proxyOption = "--proxy-server=" + seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy();
options.addArguments(proxyOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Browsermob-Proxy` is a reliable solution, But while working with the remote grid machine, Browsermob-proxy isn't really helpful. Alternatively, I found this as a working solution for my setup.

Hopefully, it will be useful for someone with a similar setup.

1. Add the ModHeader extension to the chrome browser

How to download the Modheader? Link

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(C://Downloads//modheader//modheader.crx));

// Set the Desired capabilities 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

// Instantiate the chrome driver with capabilities
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(YOUR_HUB_URL), options);
```

2. Go to the browser extensions and capture the Local Storage context ID of the ModHeader

[image: Capture ID from ModHeader]

3. Navigate to the URL of the ModHeader to set the Local Storage Context

.

```
// set the context on the extension so the localStorage can be accessed
driver.get("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/_generated_background_page.html");

Where `idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj` is the value captured from the Step# 2
```

4. Now add the headers to the request using `Javascript`

.

```
   ((Javascript)driver).executeScript(
         "localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '', 
             headers: [                        
               {enabled: true, name: 'token-1', value: 'value-1', comment: ''},
               {enabled: true, name: 'token-2', value: 'value-2', comment: ''}
             ],                          
             respHeaders: [],
             filters: []
          }]));");
```

Where `token-1`, `value-1`, `token-2`, `value-2` are the request headers and values that are to be added.

5. Now navigate to the required web-application.

   `driver.get("your-desired-website");`